# Spring Web MVC returns unprocessed views

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I've configured a Spring project to return JSP/JSTL-based views. But the templates are returned unprocessed, place holders are not filled in but remain 1:1 as defined. What am I missing?

**HomeController.java**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping("")
    public ModelAndView home() {
        String message = "Hello, home.";

        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("index");
        modelAndView.getModelMap().addAttribute("message", message);
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

**/WEB-INF/views/index.jsp** - This template is returned exactly as presented here without parsing, meaning the user gets to see the `${message}` instead of the actual message.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello world! -</h1>
    ${message}
    <br />
</body>
</html>
```

**/WEB-INF/web.xml** - I've seen that some place a `servlet-mapping` for `jsp` to `/WEB-INF/views` but that didn't help either.

```
<web-app>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/META-INF/spring/dispatcherServlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

**/META-INF/spring/dispatcherServlet.xml**

```
<beans>
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <context:component-scan base-package="my.app.controller" />

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: Your code looks ok. Which url do you invoke? Are you sure that the controller is invoked (add some sytem.out statement to verify it)?

Comment: The controller is called, I'm invoking `localhost:8080/myapp/`, the root folder of my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you missed to add the `JSTL` jar to application.

From the java doc of `InternalResourceViewResolver`:

> The view class for all views generated by this resolver can be specified via {@link #setViewClass}. See {@link UrlBasedViewResolver}'s javadoc for details. The default is {@link InternalResourceView}, or {@link JstlView} **if the JSTL API is present**.

---

So:

- If you use maven then add this to your dependencies to your maven

pom.xml

```
  <dependency>
     <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
     <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
     <version>1.2</version>
  </dependency>
```

- else download the [`JSTL` jar](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cjavax.servlet%7Cjstl%7C1.2%7Cjar), and add it to your web libs.

Comment: I did have JSTL included and it was present in my `WEB-INF/libs`. But I recently had changed the dependency from the outdated `jstl` to `javax.servlet` but only after I eventually ran `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository` JSTL would work. Thanks a lot!